# Error while building VTK for Qt using MinGW

Tags: cmake, vtk, mingw32

I'm fairly new to Qt and I am trying VTK for the very first time.
I have the following

O.S: Windows 7 ultimate
Qt IDE: version 5.3.2
VTK version: 6.3.0
Compiler: MinGW

For configuring VTK for Qt, I followed these steps:
 1. Downloaded VTK version and extracted it to "c:/vtk/source"
 2. Created additional directories "c:/vtk/build" and "c:/vtk/install"
 3. Opened Cmake GUI and specified source to "c:/vtk/source" and build to "c:/vtk/build"
 VTK_QT_VERSION to 5
 VTK_Goup_Qt checked
CMAKE_INSTALL_PRIFIX TO "c:/vtk/install"
BUILD_EXAMPLES checked
4. I clicked on "Add Entry" and added CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to "C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32". This is as instructed by VTK [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build)
5. Clicked configure and after configuration was done I clicked on generate.
6. Added "c:/vtk/build" to system path
6. Opened command prompt and cd to the build directory.
7. Typed in "mingw32-make -j8" (My computer has 4 processors)

It started building and then I was happy and hoping everything will continue smoothly so I patiently waited for it to complete while sipping on a can of soda but to my greatest disappointment it built to 77% and gave me this heartbreaking error!

```
...
...
[ 77%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libvtkRenderingVolume-6.3.dll
[ 77%] Built target vtkRenderingVolume
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I quickly copied some part of the error and pasted it on google and stackoverflow to see if someone had had similar problem but this seem to be unique. I've searched using other methods but no one had had this issue while building VTK for Qt.
Please what am I doing wrong? Pardon me if am doing it the wrong way, I'm just a beginner. Thank you

Building the VTK by typing in `mingw32-make` without the `-j8` gives more information on the error. Here is it:

```
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bi
ts/c++config.h:186:26: note:   'std::size_t'
   typedef __SIZE_TYPE__  size_t;
                          ^
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bi
ts/c++config.h:186:26: note:   'std::size_t'
In file included from C:/MinGW/include/wchar.h:18:0,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c
++/cwchar:44,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c
++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c
++/iosfwd:40,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c
++/ios:38,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c
++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c
++/iostream:39,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkIOStream.h:33,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSystemIncludes.h:36,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkIndent.h:25,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:44,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:42,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:354:63: error: expression list treated as compound exp
ression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW calloc (size_t, size_t) __MINGW_ATTRIB_MA
LLOC;
                                                               ^
In file included from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSystemIncludes.h:52:0,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkIndent.h:25,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:44,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:42,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:355:53: warning: '__cdecl__' attribute only applies to
 function types [-Wattributes]
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW malloc (size_t) __MINGW_ATTRIB_MALLOC;
                                                     ^
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:355:53: warning: '__nothrow__' attribute ignored [-Wat
tributes]
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:355:47: error: 'size_t' was not declared in this scope

 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW malloc (size_t) __MINGW_ATTRIB_MALLOC;
                                               ^
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:355:47: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c
++/iostream:38:0,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkIOStream.h:33,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSystemIncludes.h:36,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkIndent.h:25,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:44,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:42,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bi
ts/c++config.h:186:26: note:   'std::size_t'
   typedef __SIZE_TYPE__  size_t;
                          ^
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bi
ts/c++config.h:186:26: note:   'std::size_t'
In file included from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSystemIncludes.h:52:0,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkIndent.h:25,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:44,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:42,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:356:55: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW realloc (void*, size_t);
                                                       ^
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:368:58: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl bsearch (const void*, const void*, size_t, size_t,
                                                          ^
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:368:66: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl bsearch (const void*, const void*, size_t, size_t,
                                                                  ^
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:370:35: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void __cdecl qsort(void*, size_t, size_t,
                                   ^
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:370:43: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void __cdecl qsort(void*, size_t, size_t,
                                           ^
C:/MinGW/include/stdlib.h:417:70: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP char* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _fullpath (char*, const char*, size_t);
                                                                      ^
In file included from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSystemIncludes.h:53:0,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkIndent.h:25,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:44,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:42,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:36:65: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW memchr (const void*, int, size_t) __MINGW
_ATTRIB_PURE;
                                                                 ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:37:72: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  memcmp (const void*, const void*, size_t)
__MINGW_ATTRIB_PURE;
                                                                        ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:38:68: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  memcpy (void*, const void*, size_t);
                                                                    ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:39:68: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW memmove (void*, const void*, size_t);
                                                                    ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:40:59: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW memset (void*, int, size_t);
                                                           ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:46:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP size_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strcspn (const char*, const char*)  __MI
NGW_ATTRIB_PURE;
         ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:49:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP size_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strlen (const char*)  __MINGW_ATTRIB_PUR
E;
         ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:50:68: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP char* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strncat (char*, const char*, size_t);
                                                                    ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:51:72: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strncmp (const char*, const char*, size_t)
 __MINGW_ATTRIB_PURE;
                                                                        ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:52:68: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP char* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strncpy (char*, const char*, size_t);
                                                                    ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:55:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP size_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strspn (const char*, const char*)  __MIN
GW_ATTRIB_PURE;
         ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:58:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP size_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strxfrm (char*, const char*, size_t);
         ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:65:74: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _memccpy (void*, const void*, int, size_t
);
                                                                          ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:66:74: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  _memicmp (const void*, const void*, size_t
);
                                                                          ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:72:74: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _strnicmp (const char*, const char*, size_t
);
                                                                          ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:73:61: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP char* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _strnset (char*, int, size_t);
                                                             ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:77:65: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _swab (const char*, char*, size_t);
                                                                 ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:80:74: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  _strncoll(const char*, const char*, size_t
);
                                                                          ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:81:75: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  _strnicoll(const char*, const char*, size_
t);
                                                                           ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:90:73: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW memccpy (void*, const void*, int, size_t)
;
                                                                         ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:91:72: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW memicmp (const void*, const void*, size_t);

                                                                        ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:103:73: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strnicmp (const char*, const char*, size_t)
;
                                                                         ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:104:71: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 int  __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strncasecmp (const char *, const char *, size_t);
                                                                       ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:107:54: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 strncasecmp (const char * __sz1, const char * __sz2, size_t __sizeMaxCompare)
                                                      ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:110:60: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP char* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strnset (char*, int, size_t);
                                                            ^
C:/MinGW/include/string.h:115:64: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
 _CRTIMP void __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW swab (const char*, char*, size_t);
                                                                ^
In file included from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkAtomicTypes.h:18:0,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:46,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:42,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/VTK/build/Common/Core/vtkAtomic.h:85:11: error: 'size_t' has not been declare
d
 template <size_t size> class AtomicOps;
           ^
In file included from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:42:0,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:117:23: error: declaration of 'oper
ator new' as non-function
   void* operator new( size_t tSize );
                       ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:117:18: error: expected ';' at end
of member declaration
   void* operator new( size_t tSize );
                  ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:117:30: error: expected ')' before
'tSize'
   void* operator new( size_t tSize );
                              ^
In file included from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46:0,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:62:23: error: declaration of 'operator
new' as non-function
   void* operator new( size_t tSize );
                       ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:62:18: error: expected ';' at end of me
mber declaration
   void* operator new( size_t tSize );
                  ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:62:30: error: expected ')' before 'tSiz
e'
   void* operator new( size_t tSize );
                              ^
In file included from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:43:0,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkWindow.h: In member function 'virtual void vtkWi
ndow::SetWindowName(const char*)':
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSetGet.h:112:5: error: 'size_t' was not declared
 in this scope
     size_t n = strlen(_arg) + 1; \
     ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkWindow.h:96:3: note: in expansion of macro 'vtkS
etStringMacro'
   vtkSetStringMacro(WindowName);
   ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSetGet.h:112:5: note: suggested alternatives:
     size_t n = strlen(_arg) + 1; \
     ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkWindow.h:96:3: note: in expansion of macro 'vtkS
etStringMacro'
   vtkSetStringMacro(WindowName);
   ^
In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c
++/iostream:38:0,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkIOStream.h:33,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSystemIncludes.h:36,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkIndent.h:25,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.h:44,
                 from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:42,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bi
ts/c++config.h:186:26: note:   'std::size_t'
   typedef __SIZE_TYPE__  size_t;
                          ^
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bi
ts/c++config.h:186:26: note:   'std::size_t'
In file included from C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:43:0,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkRenderPass.h:46,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.h:33,
                 from C:\VTK\VTK-6.3.0\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkCameraPass.cxx:16:
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSetGet.h:112:12: error: expected ';' before 'n'
     size_t n = strlen(_arg) + 1; \
            ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkWindow.h:96:3: note: in expansion of macro 'vtkS
etStringMacro'
   vtkSetStringMacro(WindowName);
   ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkSetGet.h:113:27: error: 'n' was not declared in
this scope
     char *cp1 =  new char[n]; \
                           ^
C:/VTK/VTK-6.3.0/Common/Core/vtkWindow.h:96:3: note: in expansion of macro 'vtkS
etStringMacro'
   vtkSetStringMacro(WindowName);
   ^
Rendering\OpenGL\CMakeFiles\vtkRenderingOpenGL.dir\build.make:183: recipe for ta
rget 'Rendering/OpenGL/CMakeFiles/vtkRenderingOpenGL.dir/vtkCameraPass.cxx.obj'
failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [Rendering/OpenGL/CMakeFiles/vtkRenderingOpenGL.dir/vtkCame
raPass.cxx.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:4267: recipe for target 'Rendering/OpenGL/CMakeFiles/vtkRen
deringOpenGL.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Rendering/OpenGL/CMakeFiles/vtkRenderingOpenGL.dir/all] Er
ror 2
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The actual error message is missing. You have to get the error output, too.

Comment: Also, build log would be more descriptive without parallel make invocation. (Use `mingw32-make` without `-j8` option).

Comment: Do you have MinGW installed in more than one location? From the configuration and error messages I suspect you have one in C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32 and another in C:/MinGW.  Mixing them up may lead to wrong definitions and strange errors like those.